# Free, light-weight launcher for legacy Android devices/versions

Tags: android, launcher

Please suggest a free, light-weight launcher for the Android devices which are now categorized as legacy devices, running on **Ice Cream Sandwich or earlier** (yup, ICS is now a legacy).

Most of the launchers these days are designed for the latest range of devices, eating up quite a decent piece of the resources. So, what would you suggest to be an ideal, free, light-weight launcher that will be light on the resources and support even the old Android versions (at least **Froyo (2.2) and above**), without compromising much on the range of features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really like [Launcher Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fede.launcher) which, despite the name, is quite light and easy on the resources. I run it on an old Gingerbread phone with 212MB of RAM. There is also an [advanced version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fede.launcherproplusunlocker) with a few more features.

Even though it's light Launcher Pro has a lot of features including:

- Animations
- Scrolling dock.
- Up to 7 home screens.
- 2D or 3D app drawer.

[image] [image]

Answer (score 2):

**[Zeam Launcher](http://www.appbrain.com/app/org.zeam)** is quite light-weight, and still nice to use. Supports Android 2.2+. I've been running it quite a time on my old *HTC Wildfire*, which comes with low specs (comparable to what Seth describes).

*Zeam* supports multiple homescreens, lets you resize the rows and columns for apps on the homescreen, and runs quite smoothly.

[image: home screen] [image: home screens] [image: Drawer]

Comment: How did you get screenshots that size? Mine are too huge for an answer..

Comment: Press the [edit] link and see for yourself. Quite easy. Compare `[1]` with `[2]`, and note the added char at #1 (an "m", causes Imgur to automatically ship a "m"edium-sized version).

Comment: That's an awesome trick! I never knew that.

Comment: Neither did I. Just learned it recently on Android.SE in chat (which is why I posted it to our chat in detail as well, so others can profit from it, too :)

Answer (score 1):

**[Lightning Launcher](http://www.appbrain.com/app/net.pierrox.lightning_launcher)** might be your choice if you're a big fan of "ultimate customization". This launcher even still supports Android 2.0, and is light-weight and fast. I'm currently running it on my good-old *Milestone²* with Gingerbread.

You can freely design everything to your very heart's needs: Freely position icons (not even "outside the grid", but even rotate or scale as you wish), put widgets in folders (and even other folders for hierarchical navigation) – you will be overwhelmed by the possibilities! Though first-time configuration might take you a while getting used to :) But even for that there's some help: visit the [project site](http://www.pierrox.net/cmsms/applications/lightning-launcher.html) for tutorials and more, including video-tuts.

[image: homescreen] [image: homescreen]

Goes to the extremes, by the way:

- up to 100 screens
- zoom in and out of screens (so there are no borders)
- dock icons whereever you like (so they "stick" and don't move when you switch screens)

You should definitely check out the first video on the mentioned project site to get an impression...